# Chroot error on 64bit architecture

Tags: linux, 64-bit, shell

I am running the following command on a 64 bit debian system.
chroot /xyz/abc update-rc.d ec2 start 2 3 4 5

I get "chroot: failed to run command `update-rc.d': Exec format error". I dont get this error when the command is executed on 32 bit system.

Comment: Is `update-rc.d` a script or a program?

Comment: update-rc.d is a command to install init scripts on the system.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a machine that can boot into either a 32-bit or a 64-bit version of the same OS?  Or that your machine was loaded with the 32-bit version and you upgraded it to the 64-bit version?  Or do you have two machines that are “identical” except for the OS?

Comment: Are you sure the 64-bit machine has a `/xyz/abc/bin/update-rc.d` file?  (Or `/xyz/abc` concatenated with some other directory that’s in the search path.)  If not, that’s your problem.  If it exists, what happens if you try to run it directly, by the full pathname, without using `chroot`?  (You might want to give it args that are unlikely to provoke it into actually _doing_ anything; “`–?`” is probably safe.)

Comment: And, finally, the “dumb” question: is `update-rc.d` really a command name?  Because the Unix/Linux convention is that names ending with “`.d`” are reserved for directories.  Are you sure you don’t mean `update-rc.d/ec2`?

Comment: @ Scott: yes, it's really `update-rc.d` and it's perl script

Comment: @Kamil: Thanks for the clarification.  By the way, “@” doesn’t work with a space after it.  I saw your comment only because I manually came back to this question; I didn’t get notified.

Comment: @Scott sorry for the late reply. What i am trying to do is, mount a 64 bit filesystem, add a script file ec2, run update-rc.d on ec2 to set the run level and then rebuild the filesystem. This works fine when the FS is 32 bit. chroot fails when I am using it to run update-rc.d on 64 bit.

Comment: @KamilŠrot: I am trying to mount this 64 bit FS on a 32 bit machine, would that be the reason for chroot to fail?

Answer (score 1):

The `update-rc.d` is a perl script - you need to fix `/usr/bin/perl` in your chroot

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem, I was trying to run "chroot" on 64 bit system from a 32 bit machine. Mounting a 64bit FS on a 32 bit system worked, but chroot failed.

Works well if I do the same on the 64 bit FS. Thanks for all the answers.